# PHP: Calculate the period in minutes, between pair of dates that overlaps

Tags: php

I've got an array. Each session (startmeeting, endmeeting) describes my attendance in a meeting:

```
$attendance = [
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 11:44:27", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 11:50:01"],
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:01:10", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:15:20"],
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:04:10", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:17:21"],
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:20:02", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:30:08"],
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:25:07", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:31:02"],
  ...
];
```

My goal is to find my attendance in minutes in this meeting.

As you can see there are dates that overlap (webservice bug) so i can't calculate the real attendance time.

The $attendance array would have up to 20 sessions.

Can you give me a solution to this problem?

I tried to calculate my attendance in minutes but i can't find it because of the overlap of dates.

Comment: If you first get rid of any overlap then you can use the normal routine for calculating the minutes. Do you have that normal routine already?

Comment: Try https://github.com/spatie/period#union-static

Comment: @KIKOSoftware my routine is to calculate the attendance in minutes for each session (startmeeting, endmeeting). Then sum them all to get my attendance in the meeting. If you take a look in $attendance array you will see that some dates has overlap so i sum this attendance again in my final results.

Comment: What should be expected output from this example ?

Comment: I did understand your question. The point of my comment was to give you a chance to show what you'd tried so far. See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this:

```
<?php

$attendance = [
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 11:44:27", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 11:50:01"],
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:01:10", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:15:20"],
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:04:10", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:17:21"],
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:20:02", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:30:08"],
  ["startmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:25:07", "endmeeting"=>"2023-06-21 12:31:02"]
];

// Sort the array by startmeeting time.
usort($attendance, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['startmeeting']) - strtotime($b['startmeeting']);
});

$merged = [];

foreach ($attendance as $range) {
    // If the merged array is empty, add the first time range.
    if (empty($merged)) {
        $merged[] = $range;
    } else {
        // Get the last time range in the merged array.
        $prevKey = key(array_slice($merged, -1, 1, true));
        
        if (strtotime($merged[$prevKey]['endmeeting']) >= strtotime($range['startmeeting'])) {
            if (strtotime($merged[$prevKey]['endmeeting']) < strtotime($range['endmeeting'])) {
                $merged[$prevKey]['endmeeting'] = $range['endmeeting'];
            }
        } else {
            $merged[] = $range;
        }
    }
}

$total_minutes = 0; // Variable to hold the total attendance time.

// Iterate over the non-overlapping time ranges in the merged array.
foreach($merged as $meeting){
    // Create DateTime objects for the start and end times of the range.
    $start = new DateTime($meeting['startmeeting']);
    $end = new DateTime($meeting['endmeeting']);
    
    // Calculate the difference in time between the start and end times.
    $diff = $start->diff($end);
    
    // Convert the difference to minutes and add it to the total.
    $total_minutes += $diff->i + $diff->h * 60;
}

echo "Total attendance time: $total_minutes minutes\n";
?>
```

**Output:**

Total attendance time: 32 minutes

Comment: Man you've got super powers. You saved my live. God bless you. Thank u!!!!